# Error No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/button1')

Tags: android, imagebutton, android-image

**I thought the book had incorrect code. Tried at my home location and it worked. Found out that my eclipse was actually broken. Had to remove and re install eclipse.**

This is my first post here so if I didn't follow some of the rules please let me know. 
I tried to search and found a few post with the same error but they dealt with strings. 
I'm following Android Apps for Absolute Beginners (2nd Edition) and on page 179 you bring button1.xml into your res/drawable. When I go in layout/activity_main.xml and input

```
<ImageButton 
    android:id="@+id/button_one"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/button1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"/>
```

It errors stating that the android:src "error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/button1')."

Now there's a few things confusing me, I'm using eclipse and I have 4 drawable folders (drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi, drawable-mdpi, and drawable-xhdpi), I've went to New>File on each of the 4 drawable folders and imported a button1_focused.png, button1_pressed.png, and button1_normal.png with their respective resolutions. I've also put button1.xml in each of the folders.

button1.xml is as follows

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/button1_pressed" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
            android:drawable="@drawable/button1_focused" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button1_normal" />
</selector>
```

I tried android:background instead of android:src and that errors out as well. I see that its error'ing out stating that there is no file at src (or background). Just not sure what to put there.

Java Code
    package com.example.ui_designs;

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(context);
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button1);

}
```

Link to the screenshot: http://s7.postimage.org/3v4tu9ifv/UI_Designs.png

Comment: In Eclipse, go to the `Project` tab and click `Clean`. Does your `R` file generate? Can you see the resource listed?

Comment: I performed the clean and no R file was generated. I checked over my resources and all of them appear to be the correct naming convention. I tried to add a SS but could not due to rep. button1_focused.png, button1_pressed.png, button1_normal.png, and button1.xml

Comment: If the R file was not generated, that means that there are some errors somewhere preventing it from compiling correctly, more then likely in one of your XML files. In the prject explorer, right click the name of your project and go to `Android Tools` -> `Run Lint: Check for common errors`

Comment: Lint gave me 2 warnings 0 errors, one was "Not targeting the latest versions of Android;..." I'm using minSdkVersion="8" and targetSdkVersion="16", the other warning was The resource R.string.hello_world appears to be unused. I removed that string since I won't be using it. After removing only have that one warning.

Comment: That is very odd... How about `Android Tools` -> `Fix Project Properties` And a side note, the `R` file is not located in your `src` folder, bun in the Project Explorer, it show up in a `gen` folder in case you did not realize that.

Comment: Fix Project Properties doesn't appear to do anything. After I ran Project Properties tried Lint and same results (the one warning about version). I noticed that some of my resources have little arrows pointing to them and some don't does that mean anything? Put a link to screenshot in main question.

Comment: Stupid possible fix.... have you tried restarting the IDE...? The arrows mean that the file has been changed recently.

Comment: I just saw your edit to include the Project Explorer.... see my answer...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I thought the book had incorrect code. Tried at my home location and it worked. Found out that my eclipse was actually broken. Had to remove and re install eclipse.**

I apologize for any inconvenience I may had caused and appreciate the community for the assistance.

Answer (score 1):

According to the screenshot of your Project Explorer... you do not have the `button1.xml` in your `drawable-hdpi` folder.

If you wish to use alll of the same image sizes, density does not matter, you can make a new folder called nothing other then just `drawable` which will handle all screen densities.

Comment: I added the button1.xml to the hdpi folder as well. I tried another clean after I did that and still not getting an R file. Thanks for the headsup on the drawable I saw others doing that and wondered.

Comment: Try adding all ofthe resources to just the `drawable` folder and see if that will hopefully solve anything... If not... to be honest. I have not a clue as to why the `R` file is not being generated after everything I have tried walking you though...

Comment: Went through and downloaded all the source code from the website and went through it line by line. The code listed on the website is different than whats listed in the book. As I stated above I e-mailed the publisher. The code is so vastly different I think someone made an major error. Thanks for your support and sorry for any confusion caused on my part.

Comment: did you get everything all sorted out?

Comment: Kind of, even after just importing all the code from the book its still broken. Highly disappointed, the code from the publisher is around 90 percent complete (it works just doesn't do everything it says it would according to the book). Thank you so much I'm not sure how to give you rep but I'll research it and give you some.

Comment: I must have 15 rep to vote up your answer and must wait 5 hours to answer my own question. Will do both when the criteria is met. I'm still going to try and reverse engineer this code to make it work but you've helped me with some other stuff as a side benefit. Thanks again.

Comment: I have the drawable, and it is showing fine in the design view of my layout. Yet, I still get the error! What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem because

1: I did not add the proper image's name after @/drawable

2: I also did not add the image in the drawable-ldpi folder.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageDisplay"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/nasalogo">
</ImageView>
```

In my case I needed to add the image called nasalogo in my drawable-ldpi folder

Also this is what my values/string.xml looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

PCWorldRssReaderActivity

```
<string name="text_image_title">Decorating the Sky</string>

<string name="text_image_date">Mon, 19 Aug 2013 00:00:00 EST </string>
<string name="text_image">nasalogo</string>

<string name="text_image_description"> This is mosaic image</string>
```

Later

Answer (score 0):

Could you try doing this in your java code ?

```
ImageButton imageButton = new ImageButton(context);
imageButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.button1);
```

Comment: Not exactly sure where you want me to add that unfortunately when I add to MainActivity.java it errors out. Added java code to main question for review. Error where the R.layout and R.menu since there isn't an R file now.

Comment: You would have to add this in the java file where you want to add the imageButton to the layout. Is this a part of your main.xml file ?

Comment: So far I'm doing everything via XML. Its the way the book is teaching it. I haven't created any java files up to this point.

Comment: As he said in one of the comments above, no `R` file is being generated.

Comment: Could you check if there are errors that prevent the R file from getting generated ?

Comment: I have the drawable, and it is showing fine in the design view of my layout. Yet, I still get the error! What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I was hit by this while I was reverse engineering a project, 
"error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@color/default_bg')."

Resolution:
Added this following attribute to "/project_/res/values/colors.xml"

```
<color name="default_bg">#aa000000</color>
```

Finally it looked liked something this:

```
<resources>
  <color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>
   <color name="default_bg">#aa000000</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: I have the drawable, and it is showing fine in the design view of my layout. Yet, I still get the error! What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution to it. 
Copy all the image folders (with the same name) onto all the 4 drawable folders.
and execute android:src="@drawable/filename"
It worked for me then!

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen in AndroidStudio and it turned out that my file was named .png but was a jpeg.