# Android ImageButton display error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imagebutton

I am developing an android app, I am trying to use the android image button. I have placed my image in the drawable folder and have this in my xml code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/PanicBtn"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp"
    android:src="@drawable/panicbtn2"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:contentDescription="" />
```

but each time I try to clean or debug the project, i keep getting this error:
Error:(28, 22) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/panicbtn2').
Kindly help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/button1')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612556/error-no-resource-found-that-matches-the-given-name-at-src-with-value-drawa)

Comment: check your drawable file name or drawable file..

Comment: there can be a hundred of reasons starting from you've placed it somehow in incorrect directory, and ending with Android studio problem.

Comment: Cross check your file panicbtn2 in drawable. Name should be same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, keeping the resource or image in your case in Drawable folder doesn't get added to ItemGroup/resource group.

You can simply open the .csproj file of your project and validate that if the image name is present in the < ItemGroup > section.. it must be like below if your image name and extension is panicbtn2.png:

```
<AndroidResource Include="Resources\drawable\panicbtn2.png" />
```

If it's not present there, then you can add the same there or you can right click the drawable folder and choose add files and simply add the file again through IDE/Visual Studio. That might help.

Comment: How do i find the .csproj file on android studio please?

Answer (score 0):

The error already states:

- No resource found that matches the given name

Have you place a resource in drawable with that specific name "panicbtn2"?

Cheers.

Comment: Yes Al-Kathiri, \I have the panicbtn2 in the drawable folder.

Comment: Sawa, it could be problem with the support name/extension, have a look at the official Android documents.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

Comment: If you find my answer helpful and relevant please do accept it so as to be helpful to others too.